# How to center absolute div horizontally using CSS?

Tags: css, html, center, absolute

I've a div and want it to be centered horizontally - although I'm giving it `margin:0 auto;` it's not centered...

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width:40%;
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @LoganMzz it is not because this question has its width known.

Comment: @Davbog Not really. What is known is a min and a max, but the actual width at any time is not known.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

You need to set `left: 0` and `right: 0`.

This specifies how far to offset the margin edges from the sides of the window.

> Like 'top', but specifies how far a box's right margin edge is offset to the [left/right] of the [right/left] edge of the box's containing block.

**Source:**
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#position-props

> **Note:** The element must have a width *smaller* than the window or else it will take up the entire width of the window.
>
> You could use media queries to specify a *minimum* margin, and then transition to `auto` for larger screen sizes.

---

```css
.container {
  left:0;
  right:0;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;

  outline: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
  Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.
  Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.
  Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
  Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis.
</div>
```

Comment: Note: **`width`** is a must !

Comment: Yep. This is correct... using a "text-align: center;" and a "left: 0; right: 0;" will allow you to absolute position a div while keeping it horizontally centered.

Comment: @AlexG I just loaded the fiddle in IE11 and it works. Can you clarify?

Comment: Chrome and Firefox also allow and respect values other than 0 for left and right, but IE only plays ball using 0.

Comment: @AlexG it does work in IE11, however it **won't** work if you don't declare a **width**. I had the same problem. You have to use a width as shown in the example.

Comment: also needed `margin: auto` for it to work in our case

Comment: This solution only works if the width is defined. To me, this is a huge drawback as a lot of element's sizes are dependent on their content.

Comment: To be fair, this answer wasn't meant to be taken as a best approach. It answered the original question which was about `margin: 0 auto` not working on absolutely positioned elements. :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29261595/292060 for a good explanation of why this works.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the reason this works is precisely because of margin auto. More specifically, to quote the CSS2.1 spec: "If none of the three [width, left, right] are 'auto': If both 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values.". In other words, margin left/right becomes equal and takes up all remaining space in containing block. Spec link: https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

Comment: `margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;`

Comment: In Chrome, setting both left and right to 0 stretches the div horizontally to fit the viewport, so this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DavidSpector the original question's `width` property is set. But you're correct, if the div is centered and takes up 100% width of the screen, it could appear that the content is not centered.

Answer (score 177):

This doesn't work in IE8 but might be an option to consider. It is primarily useful if you do not want to specify a width.

```
.element
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: At this point in time, there would also still need to be a rule with a -webkit- prefix for it to work in Safari.

Comment: Unfortunately it somehow applies the transparency of the surrounding div also to the text inside..

Answer (score 25):

Although above answers are correct but to make it simple for newbies, all you need to do is set margin, left and right. following code will do it provided that **width is set** and **position** is absolute:

```
margin: 0 auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

**You can also use other values for width like `max-content`,`fit-content` etc if you don't want to set a value with units**

**Demo:**

```css
.centeredBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
   
   
   /** Position should be absolute */
    position: absolute;
    /** And box must have a width, any width */
    width: 40%;
    background: #faebd7;
   
   }
```

```html
<div class="centeredBox">Centered Box</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfect for absolute images in a row of bootstrap columns

Answer (score 10):

```css
.centerDiv {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work on all browsers

Answer (score 6):

Flexbox?  You can use flexbox.

```css
.box {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.box div {
  border:1px solid grey;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="A">I'm horizontally centered.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This actually worked beautifully for my unique case. `left: 0; right: 0;` extended to 100%, which was not an option as child element had a background color, and `left: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` didn't work because that constrained the child to 50% width. This was the only solution that preserved flexible dimensions of the child (only limited to browser support). Thanks!

Comment: The question specified absolute positioned.

Comment: how would `position: absolute` display differently compared to `justify-content: center` in a `display: flex`?

Comment: @DavidSpector This works for me using absolute positioning. I just had to add `width: 100%`

Answer (score 2):

so easy, only use margin and left, right properties:

```
.elements {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}
```

You can see more in this tip => [How to set div element to center in html- Obinb blog](http://www.obinb.com/2016/10/huong-dan-viet-css-tu-ong-can-giua-div.html)

Comment: I think this stretches the div to fit the viewport. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link please use this to make the div in the center if position is absolute.

HTML:

```
<div class="bar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar{
  width:200px;
  border-top:4px solid red;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

[Example jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amitq7000/wdt3v4px/1/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=wdt3v4px#&togetherjs=L8KAH6Ijxo)

Answer (score 0):

Both center vertically and horizontally
use `left:50%;top:50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`

```css
.centeredBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 50%;
    top:50%;
   
   
   /** Position should be absolute */
    position: absolute;
    /** And box must have a width, any width */
    width: 40%;
    background: #faebd7;
    text-align: center;
    padding:10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   
   }
```

```html
<div class="centeredBox">Centered Box</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't use `margin:auto;` on `position:absolute;` elements, just remove it if you don't need it, however, if you do, you could use `left:30%;` ((100%-40%)/2) and media queries for the max and min values:

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 2;
    width:40%;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
}

@media all and (min-width:960px) {

    .container {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left:-480px;
        width: 960px;
    }

}

@media all and (max-width:600px) {

    .container {
        left: 50%;
        margin-left:-300px;
        width: 600px;
    }

}
```