# Why does "position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; width: XYpx; margin: 0 auto" actually center?

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty proficient when it comes to CSS but today I stumbled over a snippet that got me head-scratching ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19341954/151509) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260884/151509)).

I never thought that one can center an absolutely positioned element via `margin: 0 auto` but given the element in question has a set width and there's `left: 0` and `right: 0`, it actually seems to work:

```css
#parent
{
    background: #999;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
}

#child
{
    background: #333;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/10hvkcr2/))

I always thought `left: 0` and `right: 0` will dictate the element's width (100% of it's first relatively positioned parent) but it seems `width` takes precedence here and therefore makes `margin: 0 auto` work.

Is this defined behavior? Can I find something about it in any spec? I googled around a bit but came up with nothing useful.

Comment: See http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/

Comment: @j08691 that is indeed a good link. I like the step through of the CSS process

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is accounted for in [section 10.3.7](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) of the CSS2.1 spec:

> The constraint that determines the used values for these elements is:
>
> > 'left' + 'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' + 'right' = width of containing block
>
> If none of the three is 'auto': If both 'margin-left' and 'margin-right' are 'auto', solve the equation under the extra constraint that the two margins get equal values *[...]*

As you can see, auto margins on both sides behave the same for absolutely-positioned elements as they do for non-positioned block-level elements, provided that the `left` and `right` offsets, as well as `width`, are not auto.

Interestingly, only for absolutely-positioned elements, [this applies to `top`, `height` and `bottom` as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height), which essentially means that it is possible to vertically center an absolutely-positioned element using auto margins. Again, this is provided that the three properties above are not auto, and the respective margins are auto. (In your case, this means `margin: auto` rather than `margin: 0 auto` as the latter zeroes out the vertical margins.)

Comment: *This* is the canonical answer!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the spec. Scanned through it but didn't know exactly what to look for.

Answer (score 6):

The left and right (and top and bottom) properties don't define width *per se* but rather the offset of the relative margins from the parents respective side.

In the **absence** of a defined width and with the offsets declared as zero, the width is calculated based on the offsets.

Giving the block a width or a height prevents the block from taking up all available space and forces the browser to calculate margin: auto based on the new bounding box

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) - on "Top"...and the same applies to the other properties.

> For absolutely positioned elements (those with position: absolute or position: fixed), it specifies the distance between the top margin edge of the element and the top edge of its containing block.

[**Smashing Magazine Article** with more detail](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Thanks to j08691 for the link

Comment: (The link came first from the comment left by j08691)

Comment: Updated accordingly since the other has now been deleted.

Comment: "In the absence of a defined width" in this case the offsets are declared as zero, so the width is calculated based on the offsets rather than the other way around. Hence "auto" width.

Comment: Great answer, been hard to choose where to set the tick here.

Comment: @maryisdead I'd give it to BoltClock (which I see you have). He helped improve my answer.