# How does centering an element with absolute position and margin auto work?

Tags: html, css, centering

From this [site](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/), I learned that this way can center an element. But why? What is the sequence of the elements calculating the position? How does it exactly work? Which rule has higher priority to another? What is the exact meaning of "bounding box"?

```
.Absolute-Center {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100px;//exact width
    height: 100px;//exact height
}
```

Comment: The link you provided gives a good breakdown of what is happening in the "Explanation" section.

Comment: Here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261595/why-does-position-absolute-left-0-right-0-width-xypx-margin-0-auto-ac/29261683#29261683