# Horizontally centre and bottom position image in a div

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

New guy over here. I've searched and have found similar issues but not exactly what I am after.

I simply want to know how to horizontally centre an image within a div, but also position the image at the bottom of the div (20px or so from the bottom to be precise).

I can kind of get the look I'm after by setting the container div as `position:relative`, and the image `position:absolute`, with `bottom:30px` and `margin-left: 49%`. I would just rather it be exact, rather than using left margin. The container needs to be relative for other elements I have on the page.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you actually post some related code? :/

Comment: I thought I explained it perfectly clear, I didn't think it was compulsory. Is it? If so, I will make sure to in the future. If my question has been voted down purely for this, I am quite surprised.

Comment: Too many times a question is answered and then the poster comes back and says, "Oh, my markup is different than that!"

Comment: The explanation was clear, I'd say that it's a good practice to include at least a minimal example (best case --> a snippet). *"Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some."* (StackOverflow)

Comment: No problem, thank you both. I will include example next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizontally center and vertically bottom div[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/bdow3594/)

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I tried this before (margin: 0 auto) but without the left and right. What specifically does this do?

Comment: @ColinStewart To make horizontally center we use margin: 0 auto; but we are positioning it. and if we position any element then it will automatically start from left:0; So in order to make it center use left:0; right:0; . If its worked for you then upvote it.

Comment: Okay, great. I understand now. Thanks very much. I have upvoted but don't think it shows as I am brand new. Accepted as answers as well though.

Answer (score 0):

centers the absolute image inside the relative div

```
div > img {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it almost worked but wasn't quite centred (slightly to the right).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can combine setting `left`/`right` to zero and setting the left/right `margin` to `auto`:

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.box img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ffyof90e/

Explanation: [Why does "position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; width: XYpx; margin: 0 auto" actually center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261595/why-does-position-absolute-left-0-right-0-width-xypx-margin-0-auto-ac)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, for example:

```
<div id="divid">
<img src="http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
</div>
```

You can now apply css like this:

```
div > img {
   display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;

}

#divid{
  position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
   border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
```

You can check it at https://jsfiddle.net/n4528wxz/1/